# UILabel will draw something with Chinese even if the width is equal to 0 in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, ios8, xcode6

Just creat a new "Single View Application" and add the code to the viewDidLoad method, you will see it:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 0, 100)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.text = @"中文";
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

[image: There is something, right?]

Comment: Interesting. Could you log the frame after adding as a subview?

Comment: still {{100, 100}, {0, 100}}

Answer (score 0):

After viewDidLoad() is called and before the UILabel shows up on the screen, 
iOS does multiple steps.
Some of them are

- Calling viewWillLayoutSubviews
- Calculating the layout
- Calling viewDidLayoutSubviews
- Calling viewWillAppear and finally
- Calling viewDidAppear

Most likely your view was resized when the layout was done, please check in both, viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewDidAppear what your frame size is then.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add below code

```
label.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just an iOS bug, has been fixed in iOS 10, but still appear in the iOS 8.1.

In my case, `setHidden:YES` instead of `setWidth:0` will solve this problem.